# Fedora 33 crashed upgrading to Fedora 34 and it no longer boots

Tags: linux, fedora, system-installation, crash

[image]I am a Fedora Novice User and I am begging for help. My system has been working perfectly for around 2 years. I initially installed F31 and I've been updating to F32 and F33 using the Software Center. During previous updates, the process took around 40 minutes each time.

Two days ago I tried to update to F34 and the process crashed at around 42% and got stuck for more than two hours. I forced the shutdown and my system is gone.

On rebooting, it lets me choose from F31 to F33, however all of them fail to boot and I get several messages.

I found my old F31 Live on a USB, I am able to look at all my info and did a full backup on an external HD.

1. Is it possible to fix it or should I erase it and try to install F35 from Zero..?
2. I'd like to get a list of my installed programs. Is there any file/location where I can get it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I meant the error messages from the half-installed F34 or the F33. I don't know that boot process in detail, but I guess it kind of stops with an error message at the end (or does it reboot?)

Comment: I think that will do. Now you will just have to wait for somebody with the knowledge to answer. Probably some way to finish the update from the command line. Good luck. You might want to remove the comments that do not add value to the question (I just removed mine).

Comment: It's hard to understand what and how failed, so your best option is to install afresh. Most likely you don't need to backup anything other than `/home`. Fedora 36 is basically out, so I'd install it instead.

Comment: Sorry this happened -- it's hard to figure out from here what went wrong. I'm glad you have a full backup. At this point, I think probably a full install is best. (F36 should be out next week, I hope -- we're nailing down a few final bugs, but at this point I'd suggest installing the beta and updating that rather than F35.) On the plus side, a reinstall will convert you to using Btrfs for the filesystem, which you don't get on upgrades from F31.